# Split mesh by face count

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, faces

I'm basically in a situation similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145176/separate-by-vertex-count-fast) one, except I need to split a large mesh into < 21k *triangle* chunks. Is there a script that can achieve that?