# Splitting huge .obj file into separate tiles or parts

Tags: modeling

I have been looking at several programs to check how to do this, such as Meshlab and Blender. So far I have had no luck figuring out how to cut the object into equal parts. 
I am an absolute beginner at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a way to cut a huge .obj file into tiles (which can then be exported separately)? I am looking to cut this object into 12 or 20 tiles (3x4 or 4x5).
These tiles should overlap somewhat so that we can easily see where they join with other tiles.

An example of how this .obj file would look is attached[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133086/slicing-an-object-in-4-parts/133136#133136

Comment: If you want to split it using the existing topology (without cutting), you can try my addon I am using for splitting models so they can be imported to Richard Burns Rally editor. It lets you to set max. length / vertex count for a tile. Just use the Split feature.
https://github.com/jendabek/blender-export-x-rbr