# How can I cut a complex Blender object in half?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, 3d-printing, knife-tool, select

As the title suggests, I have modeled an object, and I want to cut it perfectly in half, or close to perfectly.
[image]

But as the object is quite complex, nothing I've found on google worked that well and/or I didn't know how to apply some of the methods properly.
I tried using the bisect tool, but you can't quite make a perfectly straight cut and split the object almost perfectly in half, which is needed in my situation as I am planning on 3D printing this to full scale and I need a perfectly straight face the object can lay on while printing.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133086/slicing-an-object-in-4-parts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bisect Tool

If you need precise adjustment - open tool properties (left-bottom at 3D viewport editor) and set cut numerically.

For 3D print you would need to have a mesh as manifold, so check **Fill** option.

[image]

After Bisect operation, when cut edges are selected search for **Edge Split** to separate a half. With mouse cursor close to an one half click <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked (or box select.

[image]

Or box select a half and click <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate by Selection*

Comment: This actually will help me a ton, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Press the edit button next to file at the top left of your screen, go to preferences, select add-ons, look up the auto mirror addon. Enable the auto mirror addon. In your object viewport window, in the sidebar, select edit, at the bottom there should be a dropdown menu for the auto mirror addon. Select your model, decide which axes you wish to cut across. Then press the auto mirror button. Now in edit mode, you will see your mesh has a line cut straight down the center, with a mirror addon automatically applied.

Comment: It worked to some extent but my mesh shouldn't be symmetrical.

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you

Comment: Yup, this answer is fine, you just have to do it twice, once for each side, deleting half the result. It can also be done without the add-on, just using the _Mirror_ modifier, and the 'Bisect' option, flipped for each half.

Comment: Could always use a boolean on a plane going through it

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast response