# Strange artifacts when using Solidify

Tags: mesh, modifiers, artifacts

I am pretty new to Blender, and have run into a problem that's been bugging me for days now, and I can't seem to find any solution in the forums.

Basically, I'm trying to fabricate a vacuum manifold with a weird shape and ideally a constant 3mm thickness.  Here is one-half of the object without any thickness (I haven't applied the Solidify modifier yet):

[image]

Everything looks hunky-dory when it's just a 2D mesh, but once I try to add a Solidify modifier, I get very strange artifacts in two small strips on the cylindrical end:

[image]

I've tried using the wireframe view to see if there are any errant vertices or edges, but all I can see are these weird curvy edges (in the vicinity of the deformations) that I can't seem to select or delete like normal edges between vertices.  These weird, un-selectable edges seem to disappear when I remove the Solidify modifier and go back to a 2D mesh.

As long as I'm here, I'd also be extra-grateful if anyone can tell me how to make the thickened edges of the 3D part align so they're flush with the YZ-plane (since I plan on 3D printing this part and its YZ mirror-image and epoxying them together to create the complete vacuum manifold!).

I'll attempt to add my ".blend" file to this post.  I am very new and clueless with Blender and I'll bet I'm missing some basic concept ... literally any advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a vertex mishmash. Press <kbd>M</kbd> to **Merge by Distance** with value like 0,001

[image]

I did some more manual cleaning (*Merge by Last* to merge some others vertices that were close to each other) and *Slide by Edge* <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to straight back some edges of cylinder part.

[image]

To keep straight cut in some axis I would suggest to use *Mirror* modifier and as final touch apply Solidify and Mirror and use [*Bisect* tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208440/2214) to cut.

Topology is not good, so if you will have more issues, you would have to retopology your object anyway.

Comment: Wow, this looks excellent! Thank you so much for the help, vklidu!