# How to divide an object into several objects by loop cuts

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, geometry

I have here a cube that I’ve cut once along all three axes. I want to make 8 smaller cubes (individual objects) out of these divisions. How can this be done?
[image]
The cuts did not create an intersection at the centre like I imagined, and there is no vertex at the centre

Comment: Short answer is that you cannot... the only way is to make it separated, or make one single vertices in the middle, duplicate separated parts into separated objects and connect them to that middle vert or do it with array of cubes and transform them after that

Comment: Thanks. How do I add a vertex in the middle?

Comment: looking at your setup the best way would be to take one of the middle ones, duplicate it with shift D and pull it on axis to the place where the other one is... I don't know how to describe it like this because i dont even see your axis in your scene

Comment: Can use the method suggested here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133136/15543  Add two planes for the cuts and apply boolean 1 -> 2  parts, then again on both with other plane for each object -> 4 parts. (script would need a minor edit for irregular cuts)  btw @Destiny centre, colour, etc are UK english spelling.