# how to make 2D slices of a 3D model while keeping the color and shading?

Tags: 2d

I would like to make 2D slices of a 3D model by controlling the spacing between 2 slices.
I also would like each slice of this volume to keep its color and shading.
The slices should have the same size and I would like to be able to save them as .png.

I found an interesting post: [Render 2D cross sections of 3D Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195053/render-2d-cross-sections-of-3d-objects?answertab=active#tab-top) but each slice doesn't conserve the data that I want.

You can find an example of what I want to acheive.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

- Camera set to Orthographic
- Render as OpenEXR 32-bit
- Switch to compositor, use EXR file as a source and use two *Z-combine* nodes to clip it
- Animate Z parametr to generate slicing into image sequence

[image]