# What's the minimum size for a face

Tags: python, mesh

I'm trying to create the thinnest possible cube in Blender using python, like this.

```
mesh.from_pydata(pts, [], [(0, 1, 2, 3)])

print(mesh)
# Get geometry to extrude

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
faces = [ bm.faces[0] ]

# Extrude
extruded = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=faces)    
translate_verts = [v for v in extruded['geom'] if isinstance(v, BMVert)]

# ----------------------------------------------------------
up = Vector((1 / (10 ** 16), 0, 0))
# ----------------------------------------------------------
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=up, verts=translate_verts)
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces, context="FACES")
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
```

However, for high enough exponents, the geometry will not get extruded.

How small can  the extrusion by for it to work?

Comment: I think if we're talking floating point precision, functionally two points are considered on the same exact spot if their absolute difference is < 10^-8 units. Might be wrong though, didn't test it. Maybe your problem can be solved in another way, what's your end goal here ?

Comment: @Gorgious - I'm trying to create cross-sections as explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58153/create-cross-sections-and-2d-planes-in-blender - but in Python. So that would be the extrude size that I'd use. I _can_ work around it, but I was also curious about that per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wacky world of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), floating point implementation in CPUs and GPUs, Python floating Point, C floating point, and Blender's internal use of floating point.

If ever there was an answer where "it depends" applies it's the answer to this question; but I'm going to take a shortcut, skip a lot of uncommon corner cases, and simplify.

Blender uses what IEEE 754 calls `single precision` floating point internally.  This is also commonly `32 bit` precision.  The smallest number that can be represented in a 32 bit IEEE floating point is $10^{-126}$ but more importantly, the smallest difference between two floating point numbers is $10^{-20}$

However, the farther those two numbers get from 0, the larger the difference, and Blender uses distance, involving squaring numbers, to determine things like `merge by distance`.

So, in the final analysis, depending on the computer you're using and the version of Blender, the smallest distance possible is somewhere between $10^{-8}$ and $10^{-10}$ if your numbers are close to 0.