# Creating Multiple Cross Sections in Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Novice user here.  I want to create cross sections of a model that was imported to blender from sketchfab but have been unable to.  This problem is very similar to the prior stack exchange question/answer ([Create Cross Sections and 2D planes in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58153/create-cross-sections-and-2d-planes-in-blender)).  The difference here is the model I'm starting with consists of multiple objects.

I think the issue is that the model consists of multiple objects.

In order to join the model into a single object I tried both “control J” and the boolean modifier “union”.  While I eventually was able to join all of the objects into one, blender would freeze or give different outputs when attempting to get a cross section of an area that previously consisted of separate parts.

Aside from joining the model into a single object, I also attempted to place a plane that crossed over the model and then applied the boolean modifier “difference” to create a cross section out of the plane.  This method was effective when the plan interested a single piece of the model but would then start to give different outputs when intersecting more than one piece.

Here is a link to the Sketchfab model I am trying to create cross sections from : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/baby-f05a87806cad49feb75ac7659d55c368

Summary:
1.)  How do I consolidate the sketchfab model into a single object?
2.)  How do I get cross sections from the consolidated model?

Comment: you model doesn't help us, you should better provide your blend file with your try so we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

Without joining the model,
It seemed to work with an **array** modifier to one plane,  and adding the difference **boolean** modifier to each of the  halves of the model using the plane as the object to er...cut the baby into cross sections.

[image]

Comment: Blender did crash.  I tried again the simplest possible way and it worked just fine.  The only thing I can think of is that in the import settings for FBX I unchecked subdivision data.  This baby has 467 K TRIS and maybe unchecking subdivisions helped.